# Embedding a scripting engine in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, python, scripting, embedding

I'm researching how to best extend a C++ application with scripting capability, and I am looking at either Python or JavaScript.  User-defined scripts will need the ability to access the application's data model.

Have any of you had experiences with embedding these scripting engines?  What are some potential pitfalls?

Comment: you should really consider Lua as well, it integrates with C++ wonderfully.

Comment: Hi Tony the pony,
Another programming language has born. Is called ZetScript I don't know if you are looking for script engine yet but take a look just in case it fits your needs! 

http://zetscript.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's sure easy to embed Python by using the [Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) library (ok, ok, sarcasm.)  Nothing is "easy" when it comes to cross-language functionality.  Boost has done a great deal to aid such development.  One of the developers I've worked with swears on the Boost->Python interface.  His code can be programmed by a user in Python, with a REPL built right into the UI.  Amazing.

However, my experience has been better observed using SWIG and other languages such as Java.  I'm currently working with SWIG to wrap C++ with Python.  There's all sorts of gotchas with exceptions, threading, cross-language polymorphism and the like.

I'd look at these two places first.  As I said, nothing will be "easy" but both these make life more livable.

Answer (score 7):

Lua is also a great candidate for embedding in programs. Its very self contained, and even the native cross-language call system isn't bad.

For JavaScript, your best bet right now is to look at V8 (from Google), which is easy enough to work with.

Comment: You can use Lua easily in C++ with Luabind. Works well.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're really set on Python or Javascript, I'd give some consideration to using [Lua](http://www.lua.org). Since it's designed entirely as an embedded scripting engine, it eliminates quite a bit of overlap with what C and C++ already do well. It's also pretty easy to embed as long as you only interface between your code and the Lua engine in terms of C callable functions.

If you want to use a C++ level interface, you might want to take a look at [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html), which allows things like a Lua class deriving from (the proxy it generates for) a C++ class you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at angelscript
simple and easy to embed, c/c++ like syntax. free and corss-platform. u can get start in a few hrs.

Answer (score 1):

Boost::Python, as in wheaties answer, is a very mature solution.

Lua has a reputation for being easy to embed but I have not tried this myself.

As a user of [R](http://www.r-project.org), I am more interested in embedding [R](http://www.r-project.org) which is possible using the [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) package.  A simple example is

```
#include <RInside.h>                // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);          // create an embedded R instance 

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");       // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

    exit(0);
}
```

and there are a couple more examples in the package.  [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) essentially provides you a nice wrapper around the R engine using some of the [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) interface package.